# Is there a way to override a default dissector in wireshark?

Tags: c++, plugins, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to change the way the mpls dissector dissects packets, but I want to do it without changing the source code. I was thinking of making a plugin, but I don't know if I will be able to hijack the default mpls dissector. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is *generally* possible with Lua.  You can implement a [Lua Chained Dissector](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors#chained_dissectors) that allows you to implement your own dissector either before or after the built-in dissector is called, which is entirely up to you as to how you implement your chained Lua dissector.  Whether this is possible to do specifically with mpls though, I'm not entirely sure, because the mpls dissector registers for many different protocols, so depending on your needs, your chained dissector would need to do the same to ensure that it's called for the same protocols that carry mpls.  Have a look at the epan/dissectors/packet-mpls.c:proto_reg_handoff_mpls() function to see all the places the mpls dissector registers, then intercept those you're concerned with.